# How to implement music visualization from the microphone in Android?

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer, microphone, audio-player

How can music visualization from the microphone be implemented in Android? I am looking for a solution, which uses the android.media.audiofx.Visualizer class. This is the standard class for visualization in Android.

Answer (score 0):

The Visualizer class can not be used for this. Use the AudioRecord class instead. I learned from this project:

https://github.com/sommukhopadhyay/FFTBasedSpectrumAnalyzer

The project has missing resources, so it can not be run. But it is still possible to learn from the code. Read a buffer from the AudioRecord and then do a FFT-transformation of that buffer with the FFT-classes available in the git-project I mentioned. Then you will get the frequencies and you can visualize them.